# Should a core be "reserved" for the OS in a multi-core (SMP) Linux system?

Tags: linux, multi-core, smp

If I plan to run eight applications on an eight core machine and expect all applications to utilise 100% cpu, will the OS "get enough time" for its own tasks or should I instead run seven applications on the machine and leave one core for the OS, so to speak?

The applications will not do any disk i/o to speak of, but a lot of network i/o.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel will apply different priorities to specific processes. You can see this by running "top" and checking the "nice" column.

The time critical OS processes will therefore have a higher priority. Therefore, the OS will run these processes before your specific applications. This will make sure that these processes happen at the right moment.

This mechanism makes a core reservation pretty much useless.

Comment: +1, "useless" is the perfect term.

Comment: Yes, process priority will probably solve most things, but I guess it will also introduce "unnecessary" context switching for the application processes, right? Running all "OS processes" on one core maybe minimises this? In my original question I was also thinking more of "kernel internals" (interrupts, kernel threads, etc.) rather than processes.

Comment: These are legitimate questions indeed. I usually decide that the kernel is smarter then me and I leave things as is.